# Why am I getting HSTS error in virtual host?

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost, hsts

I have created a virtual host on my **windows** machine but whenever I enter the link I get an HSTS error:
[image]

I am using XAMPP to run the PHP server. My configuration is as follows :

1. The hosts file in **C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc** :

[image]

2. The httpd conf file of XAMPP **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

[image]

I have also tried this one :

[image]

**PS**: I have changed the port to 8080 before and I can connect to the application by using localhos:8080

Comment: You tend to get that with self-signed CA certs.   So you'd need to include your cert in your certmgr setup.

Comment: You know that `.dev` is a valid TLD, right? My recommendation is the same as [this](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/), pick a TLD that is not routable for local testing.

Comment: I have changed the TLD from .dev to .test and .cw and now I get a new error HTTP ERROR 404, although I have an index file in the folder